# Call to executable within foreach loop in R: Segmentation fault (core dumped) warning

Tags: r, linux, foreach, parallel-processing

I have an R script that does some computation and writes the results as an `input.txt` file (in the working directory). Then, still from within the R script, I call a Linux executable (`.out` file). It takes the `input.txt` file as input, does some work, and output the results as an `ouput.txt` file (to the working directory).

It works fine outside the foreach loop. Inside the loop, I get a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` warning. I'm saying it is a warning because the loop continues to iterate, nothing happens.

However, since there is only one `.input.txt` and one `output.txt` in the working directory, I am afraid that all workers might share these files and read from and write them at the same time (screwing up the rest of the script). Are these fears justified? Is there any way or best practice to cope with such a situation?

I have no way to quickly and easily check the quality of the output of the foreach loop. I could manually check it against the output of a regular loop, but it would take me hours.

Comment: Yes, these fears are justified. Don't write to file inside the loop. Export the result after the loop.

Comment: Each core also writes to the same output.txt?

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes, basically, the two text files (input and output) are shared. There is one of each in the working directory, that's it.

Comment: @Roland the problem is that this call to the executable file happens in the middle of the script (and within a function). There is much work that needs to be done when reading back the `output.txt` file. Breaking the thing into two foreach loops will be difficult

Comment: I think we need a reproducible example.

Comment: @Roland thank you, I understand. I will try. However, in the meantime, if you could just tell me what is best practice in this case that'd be very helpful. Is it completely forbidden to read from and write to files within a foreach loop? Or are there safe ways to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: How big is your input.txt?

Comment: Follow @Roland suggestion on output.txt if it doesn't burst your memory. Otherwise write to disk foreach

Comment: @chinsoon12 it varies, but on average around 100KB (very small)

Comment: @chinsoon12 thank you I will try the first option. What do you mean by `write to disk foreach`?

Comment: Pardon my English. U can write the results to tempfile("output","output",".txt") in the foreach function then merge them later

Comment: @chinsoon12 no worries. Many thanks for the advice, I will try that

Comment: Hmm tempfile is not robust. See the comments in tempfile. Check out the section on Caching to generate unique ids for each core in http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/

Comment: @chinsoon12 many thanks

Comment: @chinsoon12 I think I found a [solution](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2014-August/001907.html) but I have the additional constraint that the executable file also needs to be present in the temporary directories of each worker. Do you know if there is an easy way of doing that?

Comment: What exec file r up referring to?

Comment: I added a suggested answer, you can try it out

Comment: @chinsoon12 thank you +1! In the meantime I also reached (almost) the same conclusion (see my answer). It seems to work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on this solution: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2014-August/001907.html, it seems to work now by adding the following lines of code to the function that gets parallelized with `foreach`:

```
# save current working directory
overall_wd = getwd()

# set working directory to be the worker's temporary working directory
temp_wd = tempdir()
setwd(temp_wd)

# copy the .exe file to the temporary working directory so that it can be found by system()
file.copy(from=paste0(overall_wd,"/my_exe_file.out"),to=paste0(temp_wd,"/my_exe_file.out"))

######################################################################
# script that creates input text file, run the exe, and scans output #
######################################################################

# set working directory back to the old one
setwd(overall_wd)
```

The catches are that:

- each worker needs to read and write files on its own directory - not in the common, shared directory (otherwise all workers read and write the same files at the same time).
- the executable file needs to be copied to the workers' temporary working directories

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
outfilepaths <- foreach(i=1:numCores, .export=c("input","pathTo.outfile")) %dopar% { 
    Sys.sleep(i)
    td <- tempdir()
    outfile <- tempfile("output", td, ".txt")

    #copy r file
    file.copy(pathTo.outfile, td)

    #computations
    results <- data.frame(X=rnorm(10), Y=rnorm(10))

    write.csv(results, outfile)
    return(outfile)
}
```